# Is a constant ratio of zero a convergent sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence $ \sum_{k=1}^\infty ar^{k-1} $

if $ r=0 $ then $ S_\infty = a$ so it will look like this [ $ a+0+0+0+... $ ]

My question is, is this a converging series or not? Reason I'm asking is because I got into a heated argument about whether  or not it is or isn't. I argued that the series sum total equals to a definite, non infinite number being simply $a$ and must therefore be convergent. Counterargument was that it does not approximate to a value, where its terms would become increasingly smaller, but has single, defined value and so can not be convergent.

As all arguments go, I resorted to the Internet.

PS: I'm only a high school student so sorry for the layman writing and et cetera.

Comment: $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: @PepperSausage good point but he probably means $$\lim_{r \to 0^+} \sum ar^{k-1} = a...$$

Comment: @PepperSausage the widely used convention is $0^0=1$. And this convention is implicitly used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A series $(a_n)$ is said to converge if and only if the sequence of partial sums is convergent. For your series, the sequence of partial sums

$$
a_0, a_0+a_1, a_0+a_1+a_2, \ldots = a, a, a, \ldots
$$
which is a constant sequence and obviously converges to the limit $a$.

**UPDATE**

I did not understand what the counter argument means *it does not approximate to a limit*. It certainly has a limit...

Comment: And it certainly approximates that limit `:D`.